# PostgreSQL - Copying value from jsonb field have wrong format

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE survey_results (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    scores jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb
);

INSERT INTO survey_results (id, scores)
    VALUES (1, '{"total": 10}');

INSERT INTO survey_results (id, scores)
    VALUES (2, '{"total": 10}');
```

I want to copy value of `total` key to `risk-score` key which is done by the following query:

```
update survey_results set scores = jsonb_set(scores, '{risk-score}', to_jsonb(scores#>>'{total}'), true);
```

The problem is that the value copied is string instead of integer:

```
{"total": 10, "risk-score": "10"}
```

How can I fix that?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ea916/13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `->` operator:

```
update survey_results 
set scores = jsonb_set(scores, '{risk-score}', scores->'total', true);
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ea916/20)

Answer (score 2):

Just change the operator to `#>`

```
update survey_results 
set scores = jsonb_set(scores, '{risk-score}', to_jsonb(scores#>'{total}'), true);
```

Comment: `to_jsonb(scores#>'{total}')` makes no sense as the argument is json already. `scores#>'{total}'` is enough.

Comment: It's indeed not nnecessary.. not nonsensical though.

Answer (score 1):

You might create a second JSON dictionary and concatenate it with `scores`:

```
UPDATE survey_results SET scores = scores || FORMAT('{"risk-score":%s}', scores->>'total')::JSONB;
```